# send data TO esp8266

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I want to send data to my esp8266.

I´m using the arudino fw.

data is in the URL
I tried this:

```
String request = client.readStringUntil('\n');

    char chars[1000];
    char data[100];
    bool startRead =false;
    request.toCharArray(chars,1000);
    int counter=0;
    for(int i =0;i<1000;i++){

      if(chars[i]=='>'){
        startRead=false;
      }

      if(startRead==true){
        data[counter]=chars[i];
        counter++;
      }

      if(chars[i]=='<')
        startRead=true;

    }
    String output(data);

     // Serial.println(request);
    Serial.println(output);
      client.flush();
```

I get some data but it´s not reliable.

IF i call "192.168.4.1/HelloWorld" I want the string HelloWorld.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use WebServer to get data from AP mode. Merge the code below to your project and make your HTTP request like `http://192.168.4.1/text?data=HelloWorld`.

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleText() {
  String message = "";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++){
    message += server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(200, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup(void){
  //..
  server.on("/text", handleText);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  //..
}

void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or.... 
you could use MQTT protocol. I don't know exactly you are trying to accomplish.

I use the PubSub library (https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) + any MQTT broker to actually send data to the esp8266. I use it for home automation and control my central heating, lights, et.

My 2 cents.
Cheers!